# NSUTF8Encoding NSString to var Label or TextView

Tags: swift, nsstring

How would I take the code below and put the output in a label or TextView IBOutlet?  I would like to display the Machine and Human readable code in the label or textView.

```
var url = NSURL(string: "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=uxsWjeiQ76s")

    let task = NSURLSession.sharedSession().dataTaskWithURL(url) {(data, response, error) in

        println(NSString(data: data, encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding))          
    }

    task.resume()

   }
 }
}
```

I'm using the Xcode 6 GM.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use Grand Central Dispatch (GCD). Here is a possible solution:

```
var url = NSURL(string: "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=uxsWjeiQ76s")

    let task = NSURLSession.sharedSession().dataTaskWithURL(url) {(data, response, error) in

        var myText = NSString(data: data, encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding)

        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) {  // GCD
            self.myLable.text = myText // might need a [weak self]
        }      
    }

    task.resume()

   }
 }
```

}

You can refer to [this tutorial](http://www.raywenderlich.com/60749/grand-central-dispatch-in-depth-part-1) for more info about GCD (It is in objective-c)

Comment: Thank you very much!  This worked and I enjoyed reading about GCD and will definitely be keeping this in mind in the future!  If I could upVote, I would!  Thanks again!